# What is the strongest possible statement of the idea that "the tangent line is the best linear approximation"?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

For instance, I've just checked that that if you take the best linear approximation (in the $L^2$ sense) to a sufficiently nice function $f$ on the interval $[-\varepsilon, \varepsilon]$, and then let $\varepsilon \to 0$, you get $f(0) + x f'(0)$.

Surely we could make this stronger -- I imagine the analogous statements should hold for, say, the $L^1$ norm as well, or for most reasonable norms.  Can we go farther, though?

**Question:** What is the strongest precise definition we can give the word "best" so that we have a statement of the form "the tangent line is the best linear approximation to a differentiable function"?  (Feel free to replace "differentiable" with, say, $C^2$ or something if it makes for a more interesting answer.)

(Note: I'm aware of similar-sounding questions here, such as [In what sense is the derivative the "best" linear approximation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375317/in-what-sense-is-the-derivative-the-best-linear-approximation), but the answers there don't answer my question.)

Comment: $\mathcal C^2$ is stronger than differentiable.

Comment: @gperez By "weaken" I meant "state a weaker *result*," e.g. one that's only valid for $C^2$ functions and not arbitrary differentiable functions.  But maybe that's not in line with common usage.  I've edited to remove any possible ambiguity.

Comment: @mattbiesecker: Yes, but that doesn't *a priori* rule out that your best approximations in various norms could converge to the same thing as $\varepsilon \to 0$.  Or do you have an example where you get something other than the tangent line in this scenario?

Comment: Forget common usage, [logic has an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167016/stronger-condition-lead-to-weaker-result). So you were right, I just didn't see that you were referring to the result. So Differentiable is a weaker hypothesis than $\mathcal C^2$, but a result on Differentiable functions is stronger than one on $\mathcal C^2$ functions. Nice duality.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury There are weighted norms where it fails but I don't know of a counterexample for the $L^p$ norms.   I may very well be true (it seems to be true for any polynomial $f(x)$)

Comment: How do you define "best"? Anything close to "best fitting curve" technique? E.g. http://web.iitd.ac.in/~pmvs/courses/mel705/curvefitting.pdf

Comment: @rtybase: The question is about how we can define "best."  That said, I'm not sure I see how you can make a meaningful statement here involving linear regression that's not just strictly weaker than the $L^2$ thing I mentioned above.

Comment: @mattbiesecker: Can you give an example of a weighted norm where it fails?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury.  I retract my earlier conjecture about weighted norms.   I check enough examples (oddball weighted norms, sobolev norms)  to believe it is plausible your $L_2$ result my indeed be= true  for any norm  (at least for  $f \in C^1$)

Answer (score 2):

**If $f$ is differentiable at $0$ the the same statement holds with uniform approximation instead of $L_2$.**

*Proof:* 
Let $T(x) = f(0) + xf'(0)$.
By the definition of differentiability we have
$$ f(x) - T(x) = \mathcal o(|x|) $$
and thus
$$ \sup_{|x|\le\varepsilon} |f(x) - T(x)| = \mathcal o(\varepsilon).$$
So this would also be satisfied by the best approximation on interval $[-\varepsilon, \varepsilon]$ say $g_\varepsilon$.
In particular, for any mapping $\varepsilon\mapsto x_\varepsilon \in [-\varepsilon, \varepsilon]$ we have
$$ |f(x_\varepsilon) - g_\varepsilon(x_\varepsilon)| \le \sup_{|x|\le \varepsilon} |f(x) - g_\varepsilon(x)| \le \sup_{|x|\le \varepsilon} |f(x) - T(x)| = \mathcal o(\varepsilon).$$
Hence, we have 
$$g_\varepsilon(0) = f(0) + \mathcal o(\varepsilon)$$ 
and
$$ g_\varepsilon' = \frac{g_\varepsilon(\varepsilon) - g_\varepsilon(-\varepsilon)}{2\varepsilon} = \frac{f(\varepsilon) - f(-\varepsilon)}{2\varepsilon} + \mathcal o(1) \to f'(0).$$

**For $L_p$ average, $1\le p < \infty$:**

Fix some $p\in [1,\infty)$.
For any measurable $\phi$ denote its average $L_p$ norm by 
$$N_\varepsilon \phi = \sqrt[p]{\frac{1}{2\varepsilon} \int_{-\varepsilon}^{\varepsilon} |\phi(x)|^p\,dx}.$$
Let $g_\varepsilon$ be a $L_p$ best approximation on $[-\varepsilon, \varepsilon]$. Then, we also have
$$ N_\varepsilon (f - g_\varepsilon) \le N_\varepsilon (f - T) = \mathcal o(\varepsilon). $$
and
$$ N_\varepsilon (g_\varepsilon - T)
\le N_\varepsilon (f - g_\varepsilon) + N_\varepsilon (f - T) = \mathcal o(\varepsilon). $$